# the same @media doesn't work on different sites

Tags: css, media, user-experience

Here's the css code:

```
@media (max-width:600) {
body{
    background-color:red;
    }
}
p{
  color:blue;   
}
```

The problem is that the @media part doesn't work at all. I tested it on 3 devices (including PC) and tried to change my browser's window size. However, when I change `(max-width:600)` on `screen`, the whole thing works. What could be wrong? In addition, adding `media='max-width:600'` to `<link>` tag causes css to crash (the entire css doesn't work at all in this case) – what is this??

P.S.: the code above and adding `media='....'` works within codecademy.com codebit, but doesn't work on my site, where I test the whole thing. (http://peoples.pw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the unit. I guess you're using pixels, so it'd be something like this:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
body{
    background-color:red;
    }
}
p{
  color:blue;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fovesaci/1/

**Edit**: About the second question, you need to place it in parentheses. So this `media='max-width: 600px'` should be something like this `media='(max-width: 600px)'`.
It's a reasonable mistake since media attr has been mostly used for `print`, `screen` or `all` which have no parentheses at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the second question's still open: why adding `<link ...... media='max-width:600px'>` causes the in entire css file not to work?

Comment: Just edited to answer that. You need to match the media query syntax, so properties are placed in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />` in `<head>` tag

and css use px in width

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
body{
    background-color:red;
    }
}
p{
  color:blue;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the second question's still open: why adding <link ...... media='max-width:600px'> causes the in entire css file not to work?

Comment: this artical will help you  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries